# BibTeX or biblatex/Biber 'private communication' entry

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, best-practices, biber

What is the correct way to cite "private communications" and similar sources that seem not to belong into the .bib database.

I am using biber and biblatex with TL2016

Comment: You always have the standard `unpublished` entry type...

Comment: You suggest to insert it to the large .bib database?

Comment: If you don't insert it in a `.bib` database, you won't be able to cite it in the bibliography. You can also simply acknowledge the private communication in the text.

Comment: You can use `misc` and `howpublished="private communication". Eventually, you can put them in different `.bib` database, and then load different `bib` databased using multiple `\addbibresource`

Comment: In the end it depends on the citation style you are required to use. Most journal (and university) styles I know would simply ask you to provide it in the text as egreg suggested. This makes sense since there aren't many details to provide about a personal communication except the name and the communication type (i.e. no 'title', 'volume', 'publisher' etc). If you are required to include this in the bibliography list then what Guido suggested is a good solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The entry type `misc` can be used for private communications, and using the field `howpublished="private communication"`.  Eventually, you can store them in a different `bib` database, and then load different `bib` databases with multiple `\addbibresource` commands.

However, as pointed out by Roey Angel and egreg most journal styles ask to put them in the text instead of citing them (and including them in the list of references/bibliography).  In this case it is possible to define a filter (or technically a `check`) to remove the personal communication from the bibliography.  Also it is possible to customise `\autocite` so that it behaves accordingly when using a personal communication instead of "regular" citation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{test1,
  author = "Author, John",
  date = "2013-02-03",
  howpublished = "personal communication"
}
@misc{test2,
  author = "Author, John",
  title = "Untitled Manuscript",
  date = "2012",
  howpublished = "unpublished"
  }
@article{test3,
  author = "Author, John",
  title = "article",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = "2011"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibcheck{pc}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test { \ifentrytype{misc} }
    and
    test{ \IfStrEq{\thefield{howpublished}}{personal communication}}
    }
    {\skipentry}
    {}
}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\cites}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
  {}
  {\ifentrytype{misc}{%
    \IfStrEq{\thefield{howpublished}}{personal communication}
      {\printnames{labelname} \mkbibparens{personal communication, \printdate}}
      {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
      }
    {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
  }
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\autocite{test1} explained why the result in \autocite{test3} is outdated and why one should use those in \autocite{test2}.

\printbibliography[check=pc]

\end{document}
```

With `biber` and a recent version of `biblatex`, an alternative would be to define a new entry type for personal communications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@personalcommunication{test1,
  author = "Author, John",
  date = "2013-02-03",
}
@misc{test2,
  author = "Author, John",
  title = "Untitled Manuscript",
  date = "2012",
  howpublished = "unpublished"
  }
@article{prova,
  author = "Author, John",
  title = "article",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = "2011"}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{personalcommunication}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\cites}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
  {}
  {\ifentrytype{personalcommunication}
      {\printnames{labelname} \mkbibparens{personal communication, \printdate}}
      {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
  }
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\autocite{test1} explained why the result in \autocite{prova} is outdated and why one should use those in \autocite{test2}.

\printbibliography[nottype=personalcommunication]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For those who are printing the private communication and want it to be linked: you can put the printing into `\bibhyperref{}` resulting in: `\bibhyperref{\printnames{labelname} \mkbibparens{personal communication, \printdate}}`.