# What is the correct way to cite "private communications" and similar sources that seem not to belong into the .bib database

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using natbib and harward referencing.

I want the cite in the text to say (private communication, Svennson, 2016) for example.

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking. Is this supposed to appear in the bibliography? Are you asking if citing a private communication is alright for a thesis? Are you asking of to get *private communication* inside the parentheses?

Comment: By the way, the `natbib` manual even covers `priv.\ comm.`

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87272/bibtex-or-biblatex-biber-private-communication-entry

Answer (score 2):

```
\citetext{private communication, Svennson, 2016}
```

that is all you need to do in `natbib`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a @misc entry where you can then capture the essence of the conversation in a comment field, to maintain the information in a more complete form than in the document.

For example:

```
@Misc{Priv_Comm_Person_PCA_Model,
  author       = {Joel M. Person},
  howpublished = {{Private Communication}},
  year         = {2015},
  address      = {Anytown, MN, USA},
  comment      = {We talked about items x, y, and z and he showed me that x = z.},
  institution  = {Big Corporation},
}
```