# What is the correct reference for the handle to the current citation (BibLaTeX)?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I was implementing a custom version of [Guido's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96567/41554) when I ran into a snag. His code runs as follows:

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\cites}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
  {}
  {\ifentrytype{personalcommunication}
  {\printnames{labelname} \mkbibparens{personal communication, \printdate}}
  {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
  }
 {}
 {}
```

I wanted to customise this so it would print `(Elliott, pers. comm., 20th Jul. 2017)` for

```
@misc{elliott2017,
    author = {Robin Elliott},
    date = "2017-07-20",
    howpublished = "personal communication"
}
```

The snag for me came when I tried to include the date as the hyperlink to the bibliography entry (which, unlike Guide's answer above I want to keep).

Looking into the BibLaTeX manual I found `\bibhyperref` and `\bibhypertarget`, but `\bibhyperref` caused a lot of errors when I tried referring to `\currentfield`. Likewise, I am not sure if that is a logically sound process when I think about it. Anyways, this is how I modified the above code along with how I declare BibLaTeX and `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, natbib=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=two, sortcites=true, autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref_pers_comm.bib}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,colorlinks=true,,breaklinks,pdftitle={},pdfauthor={},pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,pdfpagelayout={SinglePage}]{hyperref}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\cites}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
{}
{\ifentrytype{misc}{%
        \IfStrEq{\thefield{howpublished}}{personal communication}
        {\mkbibparens{\printnames{labelname}, {\emph{pers. comm.}, 
\bibhyperref{\currentfield}{\printdate}}}
        {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
    }
    {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
}
{}
{} 

\begin{document}

\ldots considerably more useful \autocite{elliott2017}\ldots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Clearly, however, the `\currentfield` at the very least is wrong as I get an `Undefined control sequence.` error when I compile with the above.

So:

1. Is it `\bibhyperref` or `\bibhypertarget` that I should be using (or something third entirely)?
2. What is the handle that I can use for the above command to take me to the correct reference list printout?

EDIT: Added the info requested (hopefully) but the formatting has gone insane. Random newlines are added every time I try a space.

Comment: It would really help us if you could show us a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). The solution will depend on the style you use as well as on other modifications you might have made to the style.

Comment: I don't think `\currentfield` is defined. What do you want it to do? Instead of `\bibhyperref` or `\bibhypertarget` you probably need to use `\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printdate}`. And you don't need to pass a handle or label to it, that will be done automatically.

Comment: @moewe: Done. Should have thought of it beforehand... The reference file contains that reference as brought up.

Comment: @moewe: I was thinking based on its description in the reference that `\currentfield`refers to the printed entry in the bibliography, hence used it as a handle like I would if I wanted to go for `\ref{section:introduction}` having previously defined `\section{Introduction}\label{section:introduction}`. I'll try your recommendation now ==> No luck. Gives the error: `File ended while scanning use of \blx@defcitecmd@iv.`

Comment: Ahh, OK `\currentfield` is only available within a `\printfield`. So you can't use it here.

Comment: Yes, your redefinition has unbalanced braces it seems, with your code that doesn't cause an error, but if you change it a bit you see that. I should have recommended `\printtext[bibhyperref]` instead of `\printtext[bibhyperlink]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\mycites}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\mycites}{\mycite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \bibopenbracket
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{misc}} and test {\iffieldequalstr{howpublished}{personal communication}}}
     {\addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printtext[emph]{pers. comm\addperiod}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printdate}%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
        {\multicitedelim}
        {}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \bibclosebracket}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, the code became quite complicated since you use `biblatex-ieee`, which is based on `nuemric-comp`. `numeric-comp` needs quite some helper macros and tricks to obtain the compressed output.

---

Because it is hard to explain what happens in the code above due to the intricate changes needed for `numeric-comp`, let me explain it assuming you used a different base style that is easier to modify. Let's say `style=authoryear`.

From your original code I would have then made

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\mycites}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\mycites}{\mycite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibparens]
  {}
  {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{misc}} and
               test {\iffieldequalstr{howpublished}{personal communication}}}
     {\printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printtext[emph]{pers. comm\addperiod}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printdate}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {}
  {}
```

Here it is easier to compare and contrast my solution to your attempt.

To your questions

1. You should be using `\printtext[bibhyperref]{...}`
2. `\printtext[bibhyperref]{...}` already takes care of everything, the correct label is automatically determined, you only need to put the text you want linked in the curly braces.

Please note how I made use of more `biblatex`-y commands in your command definition.

- Do not use literal punctuation, use `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker and the correct macros. Instead of `,` write `\setunit{\addcomma\space}`. See §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the documentation.
- Do not print text directly, use `\printtext` or even better `\bibstring`s
- Use `\iffieldequalstr` instead of `\IfStrEq{\thefield{howpublished}}{...}`

It might have been even nicer to modify the bibmacro `cite` directly or at least the cite command `\cite` instead of defining a new `\mycite`.

Comment: Thanks; this is a very good and detailed answer. I especially appreciate your effort in explaining it through a simpler usage. I'll investigate the punctuation thing as well, thanks for noting it. What's the benefit of the `\iffieldequalstr` format though? The `if`statement previously used looks a bit more readable (opinion?)...

Comment: @gktscrk I prefer `\iffieldequalstr{howpublished}{personal communication}` to `\IfStrEq{\thefield{howpublished}}{personal communication}` because I like to use the commands defined by `biblatex` for this task and because it is slightly shorter. I used `\ifboolexpr` to consolidate the two `\if`s in your code into one. This is at first a bit harder to parse and maybe longer, but I avoid to call `\usebibmacro{cite}` twice. But that is again more a matter of taste than anything else.